# Ordered collection based on DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, collections

I'm looking for a way to implement a collection which guarantees order based on a `DateTime` value. My initial idea was to use a `SortedSet<T1>` with a custom `IComparer<T1>` like this:

```
internal class DateTimeComparer : IComparer<MyType> {
    public int Compare(MyType x, MyType y) {
        return x.DateTimeProp.CompareTo(y.DateTimeProp);
    }
}

var sortedSet = new SortedSet<MyType>(new DateTimeComparer());
```

However this doesn't work as the set seems to override/replace all items which have the exact timestamp. To validate this assumption, I created two collections, one being a simple list which was sorted using the `DateTime` property after its was populated, and another one based on the `SortedSet<T1>` -> The one based on the set had several entries missing which happened to be the ones which had the exact same timestamp.

What other options are there to implement such a collection?

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to add everything to a list and then sort it afterwards?

Comment: Have you tried `SortedList`? (note that sorted list is slower than normal list. because each time you access an item with index it does a binary seach, while a list will directly give you the item within that index)

Comment: A set can only contain a specific value once. Using the `DateTimeComparer` two values are considered the same if they have the same timestamp so you are only able two store a single value for a specific timestamp even though the values are different when you consider their other properties.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yes, this is exactly my problem atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way to maintain a sorted collection of items is to use a binary search tree. You could of course build your own binary search tree, however the [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) class is implemented using a red-black binary search tree so it seems smarter to reuse that class which is exactly what you are trying to do.

The ordering of items in `SortedSet<T>` is controlled by comparing pairs of items by calling the [`IComparer<T>.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If this method returns 0 the two items are considered equal and only one of these items will be stored in the set. In your case with `DateTimeComparer` you get the problem that only a single `MyType` instance with a specifiec `DateTimeProp` can be stored in the set.

To solve this problem you have to make sure that distinct `MyType` instances never are equal when compared using the `DateTimeComparer.Compare` method. You can modify your code to achieve this:

```
class DateTimeComparer : IComparer<MyType> {

    readonly ObjectIDGenerator idGenerator = new ObjectIDGenerator();

    public int Compare(MyType x, MyType y)  {
        if (x.DateTimeProp != y.DateTimeProp)
            return x.DateTimeProp.CompareTo(y.DateTimeProp);
        bool firstTime;
        var xId = idGenerator.GetId(x, out firstTime);
        var yId = idGenerator.GetId(y, out firstTime);
        return xId.CompareTo(yId);
    }
}
```

If the two instances have different values of `DateTimeProp` then they should be ordered according to these. This is handled by the initial `if` statement.

If the two values have the same `DateTimeProp` values they need to be ordered based on some other criteria. You can use other properties of `MyType` but there might be cases where these properties are equal and it is important that the method never returns 0 except if `x` and `y` refers to the same instances (e.g. `ReferenceEquals(x, y)` is true).

To handle this you can use an [`ObjectIDGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) which will assign unique 64 bit ID values to distinct instances. These can then be compared to provide an ordering.

Note that the ordering of items with same `DateTimeProp` values will be random but consistent. To control this ordering you can use other properties of `MyType` but eventually you will have to use the generated ID to provide an ordering when all properties of two different instances are the same.

Comment: I solved this by simply returning 'greater-than' (1) when two timestamps are equal.